# How to find the value inside an array with objects with the most occuring value (deep mode)?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array with objects like this:

```
const persons = [
    {
        name: "Erik",
        age: 45
    },
    {
        name: "Bob",
        age: 37
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        age: 28
    },
    {
        name: "Jasper",
        age: 29
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        age: 34
    }
];
```

How do I find the value based on a key with the most occuring value?
In this example, when passing `name` as key that would be `Erik`.

Something like this:

```
const deepMode = (array, key) => {
    // Perhaps something with .reduce?
}
```

And when called, it should return:

```
deepMode(persons, "name"); // Returns "Erik"
```

Comment: Exactly what makes the "Bob" object the one with most occurring value?

Comment: please explain what should look like your desired output

Comment: @artyom I explained that, according to this example, when passing name as key, that would be "Erik", I'll update it in the code to make it more clearer

Comment: @amn Oh no I'm sorry! It should be Erik. I updated my question!

Comment: so what if key passed for example as 'Jasper' ?

Comment: @artyom The key should be passed, not the value

Comment: Try array.findIndex(userfunction), see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can count keys by adding them in object and checking if key exists in object,then increment value, if not then add key into object, after that with `Object.keys` get keys of object sort them and get first element which is most occurring

```js
const persons = [
    {
        name: "Erik",
        age: 45
    },
    {
        name: "Bob",
        age: 37
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        age: 28
    },
    {
        name: "Jasper",
        age: 29
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        age: 34
    }
];

const deepMode = (array, key) => {
    const obj = {};
    array.forEach(v => {
      if (obj[v[key]]) {
         obj[v[key]] += 1;
      } else {
         obj[v[key]] = 1;
      }
    });
    
    return Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => obj[b]-obj[a])[0];
}

console.log(deepMode(persons, 'name'));
```

Comment: Cool! This is very readable, I benchmarked it with the other answers and it's just as performant, so I went for this one in the end :)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), count the ocurrences and reduce the key/value pairs for getting the max valaue. Return the key without iterating again.

```js
const
    deepMode = (array, key) => Array
        .from(array.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o[key], (m.get(o[key]) || 0) + 1), new Map))
        .reduce((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? a : b)[0],
    persons = [{ name: "Erik", age: 45 }, { name: "Bob", age: 37 }, { name: "Erik", age: 28 }, { name: "Jasper", age: 29 }, { name: "Erik", age: 34 }]; 

console.log(deepMode(persons, 'name'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce into a Map, find the max, then find and return it.

```js
function findMostOccuringKeyValue(arr, key) {
    const grouped = arr.reduce((a, b) => a.set(b[key], (a.get(b[key]) || 0) + 1), new Map);
    const max = Math.max(...grouped.values());
    return [...grouped].find(([k, v]) => v === max)[0];
}

console.log(findMostOccuringKeyValue(persons, 'name'));
```

```html
<script>
const persons = [
    {
        name: "Erik",
        age: 45
    },
    {
        name: "Bob",
        age: 37
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        age: 28
    },
    {
        name: "Jasper",
        age: 29
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        age: 34
    }
];
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Just what I'm looking for. Would you also know how to return the full object instead of just the string?

Comment: What do you mean with full object? The resulting count too? @FabianTjoeAOn

Comment: Oh no never mind, I thought about returning the full object (like `{name: "Erik", age: 45}`, but then all keys of that object must be the same.

Comment: Hm, you could filter the array by the matches maybe, `function findMatches(arr, value, key) {
    return arr.filter(e => e[key] === value);
}

const n = findMostOccuringKeyValue(persons, 'name');
console.log(findMatches(persons, n, 'name'));`